# Performing a case sensitive string sorting in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting

I have an array which looks like

```
var arr = [{'Id':'1','Value':'Desk'},
     {'Id':'2','Value':'skool'},
     {'Id':'3','Value':'OT'},
     {'Id':'4','Value':'sector'},
     {'Id':'5','Value':'Security'},
     {'Id':'6','Value':'Zebra'},
```

I would like to sort this array to get a result

```
[
  { Id: '1', Value: 'Desk' },
  { Id: '3', Value: 'OT' },
  { Id: '4', Value: 'sector' },
  { Id: '2', Value: 'skool' },
  { Id: '5', Value: 'Security' },
  { Id: '6', Value: 'Zebra' }
]
```

I have tried doing

```
arr.sort((a,b) => (a.Value.toLocaleLowerCase() > b.Value.toLocaleLowerCase()) ? 1 : ((b.Value.toLocaleLowerCase() > a.Value.toLocaleLowerCase()) ? -1 : 0));
```

which gave me a result

```
[
  { Id: '1', Value: 'Desk' },
  { Id: '3', Value: 'OT' },
  { Id: '4', Value: 'sector' },
  { Id: '5', Value: 'Security' },
  { Id: '2', Value: 'skool' },
  { Id: '6', Value: 'Zebra' }
]
```

Difference is the order of `skool` and `Security`. I want all my lower case letters to come up first and then upper case letters. What can I try to achieve this?

Comment: What is `toLocaleLowerCase` supposed to do?

Comment: it's looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316839/sort-item-with-parent-an-child-in-typescript-and-angular/62318656#62318656 (well, in the answer you has parentId, here you has, if  Value[0] is lowercase, parentId=Value[0].toUpperCase() else null )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var arr = [{'Id':'1','Value':'Desk'},{'Id':'2','Value':'skool'},{'Id':'3','Value':'OT'},{'Id':'4','Value':'sector'},{'Id':'5','Value':'Security'},{'Id':'6','Value':'Zebra'}];
var sort = (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
var sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => 
  sort(a.Value[0].toLowerCase(), b.Value[0].toLowerCase()) || 
  -sort(a.Value[0], b.Value[0]) ||
  sort(a.Value, b.Value));
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: That doesn't answer OP's question. The requirement was to sort skool after sector,that is sort **alphabetically** when first character are of same case, while in your case it's not sorted accordingly. Please edit the post to match the requirement

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to sort by alphabetical order or case wise? If you are sorting alphabetically you can't get `Security` after `skool` because alphabetically, `e` comes before `k`.

If you want to that -

- **If first letter of two words is same, then sort the lowercase first irrespective of consideration of further alphabetical order.**

In that case you could use following -

```js
var arr = [{
    Id: '1',
    Value: 'Desk'
  },
  {
    Id: '3',
    Value: 'OT'
  },
  {
    Id: '4',
    Value: 'sector'
  },
  {
    Id: '2',
    Value: 'skool'
  },
  {
    Id: '5',
    Value: 'Security'
  },
  {
    Id: '6',
    Value: 'Zebra'
  }
];


arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  //if exactly same strings, return 0
  if (a.Value === b.Value)
    return 0;
  //if first case of a and b are unequal return based on case
  if (a.Value.toLocaleLowerCase()[0] === b.Value.toLocaleLowerCase()[0] && a.Value[0] !== b.Value[0])
    return a.Value[0] < b.Value[0] ? 1 : -1;
  //Now return 0 if both are equal in lower case else return 1 or -1 depending on comparison below
  if (a.Value.toLocaleLowerCase() === b.Value.toLocaleLowerCase())
    return 0;
  return a.Value.toLocaleLowerCase() > b.Value.toLocaleLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;

});


//Apparently below code is not the exactly right way to do it, so use the above method
//arr.sort((a, b) => (a.Value.toLocaleLowerCase()[0] === b.Value.toLocaleLowerCase()[0]) ? (a.Value[0] > b.Value.[0]?1:-1) : (a.Value.toLocaleLowerCase() > b.Value.toLocaleLowerCase()?1:-1));

console.log(arr);
```

In the above snippet, if the first letters of any two words are same, they will be sorted based on the case of their first letter. In all other cases, it will be sorted alphabetically.

**EDIT :** As per the comment suggestion, for a sort function in TS, it should return -

- `1` : when `a > b`,
- `0` : when `a === b` and
- `-1` :when `a < b`.

So, a more correct(as well as readable) version has been mentioned in the answer.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi, I want the result to be like this only, but when I try to execute the same in my typescript code, I get an error msg `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'`

Comment: @cvg I haven't used typescript. Are you sure that you are getting error in sort function? coz I think the function is **JS syntactically** correct.

Comment: @Abhishek the function is syntactically correct but [it returns a boolean, not a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison)

Comment: @cvg I have edited the answer and now the function should work correctly.

Comment: You never return `-1` (or a negative vale). So now it doesn't return a boolean *type* but it's still only two values, not three. This can potentially lead to incorrect sorting results.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited it according to sorting rule in TS. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 0):

Just to have in your bag of tricks, if you want to alphabetize all lower case letters first, then follow that up with all capitalized letters, you can use this:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.Value[0] === a.Value[0].toLowerCase() && b.Value[0] === b.Value[0].toLowerCase() ||
        a.Value[0] === a.Value[0].toUpperCase() && b.Value[0] === b.Value[0].toUpperCase()) {
        return a.Value.localeCompare(b.Value);
    }
    if (a.Value[0] === a.Value[0].toLowerCase()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
});
```

Here is the output:

```
[ { Id: '4', Value: 'sector' },
  { Id: '2', Value: 'skool' },
  { Id: '1', Value: 'Desk' },
  { Id: '3', Value: 'OT' },
  { Id: '5', Value: 'Security' },
  { Id: '6', Value: 'Zebra' } ]
```

Comment: Please take a look on the expected output.. your output can be archived with a simple `arr.sort(function (a, b) {a>b?1:-1});
`

Comment: The expected output order is: `Desk, OT, sector, skool, Security, Zebra`. please take a look at the question. there is demo of expected output shown explicitly

Comment: I understand that.  His initial sort was from my comment in a duplicate thread he made.  We've actually talked back and forth in the thread before, so I wanted to give him this potion since the requirements were a little unclear.